# Get int value from single row in sqlite using php

Tags: php, sqlite

I have an sqlite table called **projects** with columns **path** and **count**. I'm trying to retrieve the **count** value from the row that matches the unique **path** value. The **path** value was passed to this page as an **$id** variable.

My code is below. The **$id** variable was passed to the page correctly as I can **echo** the correct value. My issue is:

1. Trying to use a php variable in a query
2. Querying a single value as an integer

My current code is below.

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $proj = $pdo->query("SELECT count FROM projects WHERE path =$id");
  $count = $proj->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<?php for ($x = 1; $x <= $count; $x++): ?>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements. `count` is a column? `$proj = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count FROM projects WHERE path =?");` and then bind the value in `$proj->execute(array($id));` if that works your `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` will give you an associative array so `$count` would need to be `$count['count']`... this presumes also that `count` is a valid column name unquoted.. check reserved terms.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it working using the prepared statement. I have posted my code in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it working using a prepared statement.

```
<?php
  $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE path = ? LIMIT 1");
  $result->execute(array($id));
  $row = $result->fetchAll();
  $value = $row[0];
?>

<?php for ($x = 1; $x <= $value['count']; $x++): ?>
```

Comment: Would do it as `SELECT count FROM projects WHERE path = ?` would be better.. then use `$value = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`. Avoid `*` and `fetchall`, that'll eat up your memory.